# Pressure increment in a room due arc flash

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, pressure

If a short circuit occurs in an air-insulated electical switchgear, there might ignite an arc flash. The enrgy of an arc flash depends on several things, but there are many calculators for determining it. As a result you usually get the energy per square-feet (or square-cm) at a certain distance R. If we calculate the area of sphere (radius R) and multiply the energy/area by that, we get the total energy dissipated(?). The arc flash can be very hot and even vaporize metals. I learned that if copper is vaporized it will expand much more than air. But if we neglect metal melting and think that all of the energy would increase the temperature of air, how we can determine the pressure increment? The assumption is that the room doesn't have any air vents or those are so small that air flow through them will be slow and we can think the process as isochoric.

I have found some information about space pressure and it comes directly from Physics standard laws that Joule = N x m = Pa x m3. But I assume that if I just divide the Energy by the volume of the room, I will go wrong? Somehow I should link the thermodynamics in the equation I think?

Comment: Do remember that an arc flash is primarily a local phenomena that does not involve the whole room (unless the whole room is in the calculated arc flash boundary). The local effects on a person may not be the same (and aren't) as the effects on the other side of the room.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you know how much energy is deposited into the air from the arc flash. Since we're in an enclosed room, the volume of the air is constant, which means the energy $Q$ deposited into the air and the temperature increase $\Delta T$ of the air are related by the specific heat at constant volume:

$$Q=C_V\Delta T$$

The value for $C_V$ is a slowly-varying function of temperature; for small temperature increments ($\Delta T<50$ Kelvin) around room temperature ($300$ Kelvin), you're probably fine using $C_V=0.718$ kJ/(kg K); a table of values is here: https://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/thermo/property_tables/air/air_cp_cv.html (This value requires that you have $Q$ in kJ and $\Delta T$ in Kelvin.)

Once you have $\Delta T$, you can get a good approximation of the pressure increase using the ideal gas law,

$$PV=nRT$$

where $n$ is the number of moles of gas, $R=8.314$ J/(mol K), $P$ is in Pa, $V$ is in m$^3$, and $T$ is in K. Suppose you have the temperature $T_0$ and the pressure $P_0$ before the arc flash. Then you can calculate $n$ by

$$n=\frac{P_0V}{RT_0}$$
Since $n$ and $V$ are constant, you can relate a change in pressure $\Delta P$ to a change in temperature $\Delta T$:

$$(\Delta P)V=nR\Delta T$$

Substituting our expression for $n$:

$$\Delta P=P_0\frac{\Delta T}{T_0}$$

So, as long as you know the energy deposited into the air and the pressure and temperature before the arc flash, you can calculate the increase in pressure.